# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, int) => Widget' flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to show data from firestore firebase , but i got an error

> 'List' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, int) => Widget'

```
 Container (
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 550 , right: 140),
                child: Text("Filter by Patient" , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 17),), 
                ), 
                Expanded(
              child :  Container( //list image profile 
                 child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection("patient").snapshots(),
               builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                 if(snapshot.data == null){
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Loading...")
                  )
                   );
               } else{
                return   ListView.builder(
                  
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: snapshot.data!.docs.map<Widget>((doc) {
                    return Card(
                          child:ListTile(
                           title: new Text(doc['name']) ,
                      onTap: (){},
                    ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                   );
                }
            },
          ),
          ),
```

I printed snapshot.data!.docs and this the result

> I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance
> of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']
>
> Another exception was thrown: type 'List' is not a subtype of
> type '(BuildContext, int) => Widget'
>
> Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
> I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance
> of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] I/flutter ( 6015): [Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of
> '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']
>
> Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> Another exception was thrown: type 'List' is not a subtype of
> type '(BuildContext, int) => Widget'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to use `itemBuilder`. You have to do something like this:

```dart
// if snapshot.data!.docs is a List
List value = snapshot.data!.docs;
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder(context, index){
    return Card(
      child:ListTile(
      title: Text(value[index]['name']) ,
      onTap: (){},
    ),
  }
)
```

Check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank yo for the informations , after editing the code , the problem solved but i got another errors:  _RenderListTile#5fbe2 relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: Try to add `height` and `width` to the first or second `Container` of the tree. Also remove `Expanded`, it should only be a direct child of `Row` or `Column`.

Comment: I removed Expanded and added a height and width but i’mStill getting the same error

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the whole error and tell me the parent of the widget wrapping the code you posted (I mean two parents above) ?

Comment: I post the error in another question , here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571098/boxconstraints-forces-an-infinite-width-flutter

Comment: I just checked the link, and the first answer will solve the problem.

Comment: I tried the answer but nothing in the screen

Comment: I there another errror or something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245479/discussion-between-nullonprog-and-fsbelinda).