# BoxConstraints forces an infinite width Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is the error that I got

```
> Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> _RenderListTile#bfb7d relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderPadding#9ad87 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderPadding#24132 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderSemanticsAnnotations#09519 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderPointerListener#6e77f relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderSemanticsAnnotations#39ab6 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderMouseRegion#77c75 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderSemanticsAnnotations#39f2d relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e877e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> _RenderInkFeatures#8f433 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderCustomPaint#ded6d relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderPhysicalShape#9e5aa relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderPadding#ef085 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e3df0 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderRepaintBoundary#88219 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 
> Another exception was thrown:
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
```

And this is the code :

```dart
return Container(
height: size.height,
width: size.width,
child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: <Widget>[
  Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 490, right: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(19),
          topRight: Radius.circular(19),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(19),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(19)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 185, 203, 203).withOpacity(0.5),
          spreadRadius: 5,
          blurRadius: 7,
          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 550, right: 140),
    child: Text(
      "Filter by Patient",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 17),
    ),
  ),
  Container(
    //list image profile
    width: 200,
    height: 80,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 650, right: 140),
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db.collection("patient").snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        List value = snapshot.data!.docs;
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print(snapshot.data!.docs);
                return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(value[index]['imageURL']),
                  ),
                ));
              });
        }
      },
    ),
  )
]));
```

Comment: Are you using this container as `body:Container..`?

Comment: Yes I don't know if this is the correct way to do it ! I'm a beginer on flutter

Answer (score 0):

The issue rise using `ListTile` inside horizontal list, on listView parent you are using `width:200` and it can be set on `ListTile` width. You can wrap `Card` or `ListTile` with a sized widget by providing width, and it will solve the issue.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 200,
    child: Card(
      child: ListTile(
```

I will encourage you to check [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) for using sizes and [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Check  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI) to learn more about Unbounded height/ width.